# Voltage Sensor - Differential output

Tags: voltage-measurement

How does this voltage sensor provide a differential output from a single input?
[image]

Data sheet: https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/AV02-3563EN

Comment: The internal workings of the chip are not explained in enough detail to offer anything other than an opinion. Do you know how a basic simple circuit can do this? By "basic" I mean a chip that takes a single ended input and produces a differential output without all the fuss of opto-isolation and sigma delta modulation (which, of course, is not relevant).

Comment: Unless I am wrong, Something is strange. How is it possible to define a "full-scale differential voltage input range" ... with a single input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the datasheet, the outputs have an offset of 1.23V, and the maximum voltage swing for each output is 2.46V:

[image]

Think of it like this: If one of the outputs is a 1.23Vpk sine then the output will hit 0 when the sine gets its minimum (i.e. negative peak).

With this, you don't need any negative supply voltage.

Looking at the input requirement, I can say that the chip accepts AC voltages  with offset only (up to 2V w.r.t. GND1).

Regarding how it's done, well, we don't have any info about the internals but it can be done with two single-supply op amps (remember the virtual ground concept).